# Jquery insert error message returned by PHP via Json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to submit a form via AJAX.I send my form to PHP which return error messages if there are via Json.

If there are no error, the code work well. But if not... I cannot insert error message. I don't understand why.

Here is what I would like to do :

```
function addWishlist(){
    var formdata = $("#addwishlist").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Shawili/<?= $profile['username'] ?>/addwishlist/",
        data: formdata,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json){
            if(json.valid == 'ok') {
              $('#addwishlist').each(function(){
                                this.reset();
                            });
          } else {
              $.each( json, function( key, value ) {
                $('#'+key).before('<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-5"><span class="label label-danger">' + value + '</span></div></div>');
              });
          }

        }
    });

}
```

This code is working :

```
function addWishlist(){
    var formdata = $("#addwishlist").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Shawili/<?= $profile['username'] ?>/addwishlist/",
        data: formdata,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json){
            if(json.valid == 'ok') {
              $('#addwishlist').each(function(){
                                this.reset();
                            });
          } else {
              $.each( json, function( key, value ) {
                alert(key +':'+ value);
              });
          }

        }
    });

}
```

This code is'nt :

```
function addWishlist(){
    var formdata = $("#addwishlist").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Shawili/<?= $profile['username'] ?>/addwishlist/",
        data: formdata,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json){
            if(json.valid == 'ok') {
              $('#addwishlist').each(function(){
                                this.reset();
                            });
          } else {
              $('#title').html('<p>test</p>')
          }

        }
    });

}
```

The html form is shown via AJAX because I'm using a tabs system. (Each tab is loaded via AJAX when user click on it) The JS script is located at the end of the layout.
Here is a part of the form :

```
<div id="title" class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="title">Title</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" placeholder="" name="title" class="form-control"></div></div>
```

However, when I use Firebug I can see the changes in the html structure but nothing appends in the page.

Here is my tab loading function :

```
$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
    var href = this.hash;
    var pane = $(this);

    // ajax load from data-url
    $(href).load(url,function(result){      
        pane.tab('show');
    });
});
```

And here is Firebug screenshot :

[image]

Comment: do you see errors in console of firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind first in another not DOM element, something like this:

```
$('#otherDivContent').find('#title').html('<p>test</p>');
```

Where `#otherDivContent` is a div(or other element) that you have initially on your page.